# New checkbox in custom widget isn't saving data

Tags: functions, widgets, actions, sidebar, customization

I'm trying to develop my own widget. Mostly cause I want to understand Wordpress functionality (yes I'm completely new. First ever try to extend wordpress)

I want to add a function to display post thumbnail option in the recent post widget.

I have copied the original widget and added function for a new checkbox (for now) 
My problem is that the checkbox status (checked or not checked) isn't working. When I hit save, the checkbox becomes unchecked. If I force the value to checked, the code to display a thumbnail works.

Here is my current code
My changes is in relation to
`$show_thumbnail = isset( $instance['show_thumbnail'] ) ? $instance['show_thumbnail'] : false;`

```
<?PHP

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Plugin Name: Recent Posts Widget
    Plugin URI: http://www.webadelic.co.uk
    Description: Displays recent blog posts from a standard post type.
    Version: 1.0
    Author: David Martin
    Author URI: http://www.webadelic.co.uk
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Add webadelic_recent_blog_widgets function to widgets_init, this will load the widget.
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'svib_widget_recent_entries' );

// Register the widget.
function svib_widget_recent_entries() {
    register_widget( 'svib_widget_recent_entries' );
}

class svib_widget_recent_entries extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'svib_widget_recent_entries', 'description' => __( "Your site&#8217;s most recent Posts.") );
        parent::__construct('recent-posts', __('Recent Posts'), $widget_ops);
        $this->alt_option_name = 'svib_widget_recent_entries';

        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        $cache = array();
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'svib_widget_recent_posts', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = array();
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();
        extract($args);

        $title = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Recent Posts' );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        $number = ( ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number )
            $number = 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? $instance['show_date'] : false;

        $show_thumbnail = isset( $instance['show_thumbnail'] ) ? $instance['show_thumbnail'] : false;

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for the Recent Posts widget.
         *
         * @since 3.4.0
         *
         * @see WP_Query::get_posts()
         *
         * @param array $args An array of arguments used to retrieve the recent posts.
         */
        $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
            'posts_per_page'      => $number,
            'no_found_rows'       => true,
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
        ) ) );

        if ($r->have_posts()) :
?>
        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
        <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
            <?php if ( $show_thumbnail ) : ?>
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail (); ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
<?php
        // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
        wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_recent_posts', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_flush();
        }
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_date'] : false;
        $instance['show_thumbnail'] = isset( $new_instance['show_thumbnail'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_thumbnail'] : false;
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['svib_widget_recent_entries']) )
            delete_option('svib_widget_recent_entries');

        return $instance;
    }

    function flush_widget_cache() {
        wp_cache_delete('widget_recent_posts', 'widget');
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title     = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $number    = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_date'] : false;
        $show_thumbnail = isset( $instance['show_thumbnail'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_thumbnail'] : false;
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $show_date ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post date?' ); ?></label></p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $show_thumbnail ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_thumbnail' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_thumbnail' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_thumbnail' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post Thumbnail?' ); ?></label></p>


<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem lies within redefining a widget: a widget with the ID "recent-posts" already exists, and that's causing some strange behaviour when saving the widget. This is possibly due the callback on saving the widget being on the original widget class `WP_Widget_Recent_Posts`).

It's not really a good idea anyway to redefine a widget; the widgets API is not intended to be used that way. Your problem can be fixed by using a unique widget ID; replace 'recent-posts' by another ID in

```
parent::__construct('recent-posts', __('Recent Posts'), $widget_ops);
```

And while you're at it, rename the widget to avoid having duplicate widget titles:

```
parent::__construct( 'myplugin-recent-posts', __( 'My plugin: Recent Posts', 'myplugin_textdomain' ), $widget_ops );
```

Comment: First, thank you very very much for your answer. It fixed the problem.

Now to, what probably is a stupid question, but if redefining a widget is a bad idea, what is the pref solution? Make a plugin?